# Building bnx2 module for Ubuntu with kernel 4.8

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, kernel-module

I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04.5 with kernel 4.4.0-111 to Ubuntu 16.04.6 with kernel 4.8.0-56
and lost my network card Broadcom BCM5716 on the server Dell R510. I found that there is no compiled module bnx2 in the OS.

I did several attempts to compile the module after I found source of it but no luck.

Could anybody help me with this issue, I'm not so experienced with patching kernel modules and investigating the errors.

Comment: File a bug to the distro tracker. Seems quite fair that they must fix this.

Comment: To the topic, you may download sources `apt-get source ...` of Linux kernel, patch it accordingly and rebuild. On your server it shouldn't take much time.

Comment: This Q though suggested that the module is there: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350350/ubuntu-16-10-not-recognising-bnx2-network-interfaces Are you sure it's not the same issue you experienced? Also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-hwe-edge/+bug/1761228

Comment: I tried to compile the module but faced several errors.

Comment: I don't have the module now. There is no bnx dir in the /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom. But there are bnx firmwares int the required dir.

Comment: root@sio-:~/Bcom_LAN_17.8.4.2_Linux_Source_18.2.0.7/NetXtremeII/netxtreme2-7.8.55#
root@sio-:~/Bcom_LAN_17.8.4.2_Linux_Source_18.2.0.7/NetXtremeII/netxtreme2-7.8.55# make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-56-generic'
cat: /driver/COMPAT: No such file or directory
  Building modules, stage 2.
cat: /driver/COMPAT: No such file or directory
  MODPOST 0 modules
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-56-generic'
root@sio-:~/Bcom_LAN_17.8.4.2_Linux_Source_18.2.0.7/NetXtremeII/netxtreme2-7.8.55#

Comment: Why are you compiling out-of-tree modules?! Just file a bug to Ubuntu or (re)build kernel yourself.